# Can someone help to turn this sidebar into hamburger base on ratio?

Tags: html, css

Hey i new to this web code thing, and i need help from all of you.
I have side menu that i need to convert it to hamburger menu when the screen is small mobile sized.

I need all of this content `<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">` to be hamburger menu on mobile scale ratio

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 300px;
  width: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #858585;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #0E73B9;
}

main .sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.material-icons,
.icon-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.material-icons {
  margin-right: 30px
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.dropdown {
  position: block;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  /*box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);*/
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #858585;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .down {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="#"><span><i class="material-icons">home</i><span class="icon-text">Dashboard</span></a><br>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="down">
        <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">info</i><span class="icon-text"></span>Monitoring</a></span>
        </a><br>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="index.html">Reader</a>
        <a href="rfid.html">RFID</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="settingakun.html"><i class="material-icons">settings</i><span class="icon-text"></span>Settings</span></a><br>
    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">logout</i><span class="icon-text"></span>Logout<span></a>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, I guess you can do further editing to match style that you use but most of the css you can re-use. If you check snippet from below in full screen and try to resize your browser you will see how your menu switch to hamburger menu when window size becomes less than `1000px`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 300px;
  width: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #858585;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #0E73B9;
}

main .sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.material-icons,
.icon-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.material-icons {
  margin-right: 30px
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.dropdown {
  position: block;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  /*box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);*/
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #858585;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .down {
  background-color: white;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#menuToggle a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  /* hide this */
  z-index: 2;
  /* and place it over the hamburger */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}


/*
 * Just a quick hamburger
 */

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}


/* 
 * Transform all the slices of hamburger
 * into a crossmark.
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}


/*
 * But let's hide the middle one.
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}


/*
 * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}


/*
 * Make this absolute positioned
 * at the top left of the screen
 */

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  display: none;
}


/*
 * And let's slide it in from the left
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>

<body>
  <nav role="navigation">
    <div id="menuToggle">
      <!--
    A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
    so you can use the :checked selector on it.
    -->
      <input type="checkbox" />

      <!--
    Some spans to act as a hamburger.
    
    They are acting like a real hamburger,
    not that McDonalds stuff.
    -->
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>

      <!--
    Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button
    but hey, it's pure CSS magic.
    -->
      <ul id="menu">
        <a href="#">
          <li><i class="material-icons">home</i>Dashboard</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li><i class="material-icons">info</i>Monitoring</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li><i class="material-icons">settings</i>Settings</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li><i class="material-icons">logout</i>Logout</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="#"><span><i class="material-icons">home</i><span class="icon-text">Dashboard</span></a><br>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="down">
        <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">info</i><span class="icon-text"></span>Monitoring</a></span>
        </a><br>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="index.html">Reader</a>
        <a href="rfid.html">RFID</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="settingakun.html"><i class="material-icons">settings</i><span class="icon-text"></span>Settings</span></a><br>
    <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">logout</i><span class="icon-text"></span>Logout<span></a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you  so much

Comment: If you find it helpful and if answered your question please mark it as answer. Thanks!